# How to set the width of the text box when using Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following line in my view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)%>                    
</div>
```

How do I define the width of the text box?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A reusable solution is to set the width in your css file

```
.wide
{
     width: 300px;
}
```

then set it using the markup above

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class= "wide" })%>
```

Answer (score 66):

This worked for me for the one-offs, pretty verbose though:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { style="width:50px;" })%>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can attach it as an attribute. Try this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { style = "width:20em;" })%>                     
</div>
```

Comment: what is em in `20em` stand for?

Comment: Also I notice another difference between your answer and Josh's answer above. YOu said `<%=` and Josh has `<%:` - are these the same?

Comment: No VoodooChild, <%=  is equivalent to Response.Write(foo) and <%: is the equivalent to Response.Write(Html.Encode(foo)) that's the difference

Comment: @VoodooChild: "Originally the unit was derived from the width of the capital "M" in the currently used typeface." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)

Comment: I still don't get the difference, please elaborate!

Comment: This was a year ago but <%: will encode the string to be HTML safe.

Answer (score 3):

You can do also like this

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "readonly", "true" }, { "style", "width:250px;" } })
```

Answer (score 2):

To me it worked by adding the "input" in the CSS for @Html.TextBoxFor:

CSS:

```
.campoTexto input {
    width: 50px;
}
```

For:

```
<div class="campoTexto">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nombre)
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the properties like "TextBoxFor,TextArea" etc instead of "EditorFor"...
Lot of people when use scaffolding, they have to change the fields by
themselves or data annotations for in model like `[DataType(Multiline)]`

Comment: Worked for me. The attribute is actually [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]