# MVC3 CSS Textbox Styling

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know this post is probably identical to many others (for example [How to set the width of the text box when using Html.TextBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517384/how-to-set-the-width-of-the-text-box-when-using-html-textboxfor)) but I am having real trouble assigning a CSS class to a textbox.

My CSS is simple:

```
.myInput {
         width: 12em;
        border-color: red;   
    }
```

And my textbox is declared using:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DepostAmount, new {@class= "myInput"})
```

However the textbox is not styled any differently. Looking at the source of the page, I can see that the class is indeed included within the objects markup:

```
<input class="myInput" id="DepostAmount" name="DepostAmount" type="text" value="" />
```

I can also see the CSS for .myInput is being rendered too.

Comment: Maybe you have styles that are overriding your given style. Check with developer tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In the sample application generated by visual studio, there was a selector selecting all inputs which was overriding my own css class.

```
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever your write in cshtml pages final output is plain html,
so add classes to your elements(input types, div, etc) and write write css classes for it..
if you don't want css generated by vs then modify it according to your needs.
thanks , have a nice day..